# Database in recovery issues

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Rackspace Could server running Widows Server 2012 and an instance of MS SQL Server 2012 Web Edition.

Ealier today a website using a database on that server was reporting a SQL Query timeout on a particular table in a database. Nothing unusual / anything had changed on the webserver or the SQL server.

I restarted MS SQL Server to see if that would solve the issue. Once restarted I opened Management Studio and opened the database tree to take a look at the tables and got the error 'The database xxxx is not accessible. (ObjectExplorer)".

I then tried to take the database offline and got the 1st error:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

------------------------------

Cannot show requested dialog.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Cannot show requested dialog. (SqlMgmt)

------------------------------

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

Database 'xxxx' is being recovered. Waiting until recovery is finished. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 922)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.3128&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=922&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

I then tried to detach the database and got the 2nd error:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Detach database failed for Server 'ORIGIN1'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.0.3000.0+((SQL11_PCU_Main).121019-1325+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Detach+database+Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

Cannot detach the database 'xxxxx' because it is currently in use. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3703)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.3128&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=3703&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

The database size is 1.8GB.

Any ideas?